# Can classes like QString be safely transferred across DLL boundaries, assuming the same compiler?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, dll

I know that when writing (dynamic) plugins in C++, memory allocated by the plugin should be deallocated by the plugin as well. The same obviously applies to DLLs in general.

*Assumption for the following: The executable, all plugins and all dependencies (like Qt) will always be built with the same compiler*

Since classes like `QString` use mechanisms like shallow copy and thus internal data pointers:

If a plugin returns a locally defined `QString` by (shallow) copy to the executable, and the copy goes out of scope in the executable, does that deallocate memory in the wrong process?

Example Code:

```
// Defined in a DLL which is loaded at runtime
class SamplePlugin : IPlugin
{
public:
    QString getSomeStringData() const override
    {
        return "Hello World"
    }
}

// Defined in the executable
void Test( PluginManager* pluginManager )
{
    for( auto plugin : pluginManager->loadPlugins() )
    {
        auto stringData = plugin->getSomeStringData();
        doSomethingWith( stringData )

    } // stringData goes out of scope here - is this a problem?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, 2 Dlls may share objects *if*:

1. memory allocated by one may be deleted safely by the other (i.e. they share the same *shared* runtime [and any other dependant libraries]).
2. The code within both has been compiled with the same compiler and compatible compiler options.
3. The objects do not rely on any static state which is local to the shared library, or
4. The objects have been marked DllExport/Import as appropriate.

Note that even if all the above is satisfied, and the objects in the 2 Dlls depend on the same static library, you may well get problems (if that static library has state with global linkage, such as a static variable).